# Java date DST adjusts my date / time

Tags: java, date, timezone, dst

I have a function that accepts 2 set of dates (`start date`, and `end date`) that will be used for my match engine

I have to know if the `start_date1` & `end_date1` is inside `start_date2` & `end_date2`

Fast forward : I already have the right computation and implementation when I run it in local..
But when I run it in cloud.. This is the result

Result:

```
(DATETIME IN SQL)

input > **start_date1** : Apr 1, 2016  6:00am

input > **end_date1** : Apr 1, 2016 7:00pm

--

(TIMESTAMP IN SQL)

input > **start_date2** : Apr 1, 2016 6:00am

input > **end_date2** : Apr 1, 2016 6:00pm


output : true
--------------
```

As you can see the output must be false.. I think it is being adjusted by the DST..
Please tell me if there is a way to disregard DST or turn it off or the easiest way to disregard it..

BTW, I'm using Java 7.. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to create a test that sends `end_date1 = 6:59pm` to see if your theory is correct ?

Comment: I'm only doing a per hour change so.. nahh. In my loggers it really adjusts for 1 hour only. even created a boolean matrix to investigate that match per hour..

Comment: plus, I already handled that if the date/time exceeds even 1 second it will adjust one hour.

Comment: What database? what is the column type? how do you retrieve it in Java?

Comment: I'm using MySQL, the column type is written in my post. I'm retrieving it as a date.util

Comment: You have not supplied enough info for us to help. Show the least amount of source code that can demonstrate the problem. Also, edit your Question with clarifications rather than posting as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen if your local and cloud time zone are different. Make sure that the two time zone are the same.

You can change your time zone with this command :

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("yourTimeZone"));
```

You can also choose time zone whithout DST, like "UTC" :

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: Beware that changing your JVM’s current default time zone **immediately affects all other code** in all other threads in all other apps running in that JVM. I suggest you do so only as a last resort to solve a very serious problem.